# Fancytree with multiple plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, fancytree

I am using fancytree with the "edit", "dnd" and "contextMenu" plugins and there seems to be a conflict with the "edit" and the "dnd" plugins. I can run my page without the "edit" plugin and the drag/drop works well and I can run my page without the drag/drop plugin and the the "edit" seems to work well. But, with both, I run into problems.

The problem: the user double clicks a node to start editing and then changes their mind and just clicks on another node, the software doesn't seem to recognize that a .blur took place. So the cursor stays inside the first nodes editing box. I'm not sure if this is due to the tree having an _unbind() applied prior to editing or not. If the user hits the tab key or the enter key all is well but that isn't exactly the behavior I'm after.

I have downloaded the samples and each of the pages - dnd and edit - work great independently but even those show this behavior when combined.

Has anybody run into this before? If so, what was the fix? I've been working on this for days and just can't seem to make any more progress towards a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to open an issue for that on the project site.

Comment: I took your advice and just opened an issue.